# How to launch with custom profile?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i need to launch with custom profile user data that sets already. I need to setup for gmail login. So first i launch manually by typing path and login. what i want is when i use selenium to launch that profile. it logon already. but, now its like a seperate profile when launch with selenium whereas **custom-profile** name is same

> C:\Users\Pandora\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>   --profile-directory="custom-profile"

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Pandora\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\custom-profile")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"d:/automation/chromedriver.exe", options=options)
driver.get("https://mail.google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the argument be similar to below?

```
"--user-data-dir==C:\\Users\\Pandora\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\custom-profile"
```

Comment: What does it say? does it load the default profile? More information would help

Answer (score 0):

The user-data-dir argument should conclude at User Data and the desired profile is set using the profile-directory argument.
The default profile is profile 1.
Like so,

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User 
Data")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 5")
```

Also note that Selenium won't run in a custom profile unless all other instances of chrome are closed